# The topology on $S^{\infty}$

Tags: general-topology

If we consider the standard embeddings $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$, then the colimit (in Top) of this system will be $\bigoplus_1^{\infty} \mathbb R$ with the box topology.
(See [Compare the final (weak) topology and the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871209/compare-the-final-weak-topology-and-the-box-topology-on-mathbbr-infty?rq=1) ). Let $S^\infty \subset \bigoplus_1^{\infty} \mathbb R$ be the unit shpere with respect to the $l^2$ norm.

Is restricting the box topology to $S^\infty$ the same as restricting the product topology to $S^\infty$? Seems wrong, but I saw this claim somewhere. If not, are they nonetheless homeomomorphic? Or perhaps we need to take the "full" sphere inside $l^2$ with either topology?

The product topology is much more convenient to use.

Comment: I might be wrong but here is what came to my mind. Fix a point $p\in S^\infty$. Let $B_r(p)$ be the $r$-box around $p$. For small enough $\varepsilon$, I think $B_\varepsilon(p)\cap S^\infty$ will be open in box topology but not open in product topology.